# How to unsubscribe a firestore snapshot listener when component will unmount?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-typescript, react-thunk

I am using React with Typescript and redux with the thunk layer. So, I defined one of my action as follows and it deals with a firestore snapshot listener.

```
export const getEmployees = () : ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, TableActions> => {

    const db = fire.firestore();

    return async dispatch => {
        db.collection("collection_name").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            // body
        });
    }
};
```

and I dispatched it as following when a component will mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getEmployees());
},[]);
```

So, my question is there any best way to unsubscribe the listener when a component will unmount?

Comment: I have found a stackoverflow thread and a link to unsubscribe from firestore which can be useful.[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905711/componentwillunmount-to-unsubscribe-from-firestore [2] https://brandonlehr.com/reactjs/2018/11/08/unsubscribing-from-firestore-realtime-updates-in-react